# How to run a Suave Application in the background?

Tags: background, suave

It seems that doing `mono AppName.exe &` is not working. Do I need to change the default configuration of the suave app ir something else?

Do I need to use the async version of startWebServer?

Comment: "Not working"?.

Comment: I do a request and nothing happens. If I run it without the & it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work with `nohup mono AppName.exe &`. I'm not using the async version of startWebServer. But, is this the best way?